# Accessing preview image of SLComposeServiceViewController

Tags: ios, swift, share, slcomposeviewcontroller, share-extension

Has anyone had any luck capturing the image preview, a screenshot of the website, that apple presents in the its share extension for safari webpages, without having to simply replicate the functionality?